# Separating Date and Time in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a data file with timestamps that look like this:

[image: Time 3/4/2022 15:00 3/4/2022 14:00 3/4/2022 13:00]

It gets loaded into pandas with a column name of "Time". I am trying to create two new datetime64 type columns, one with the date and one with the time (hour). I have explored a few solutions to this problem on StackOverflow but am still having issues. Quick note, I need the final columns to not be objects so I can use pandas and numpy functionality.

I load the dataframe and create two new columns like so:

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\...\\xyz.csv')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.date
df['Hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.time
```

This works but the Date and Hour columns are now objects.

I run this to convert the date to my desired datetime64 data type and it works:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

However, when I try to use this same code on the Hour column, I get an error:

```
TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime
```

I did some digging and found the following code which runs:

```
df['Hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Hour'], format='%H:%M:%S')
```

However the actual output includes a generic date like so:

[image]

When I try to run code referencing the Hour column like so:

```
HourVarb = '15:00:00'
df['Test'] = np.where(df['Hour']==HourVarb,1,np.nan)
```

It runs but doesn't produce the result I want.

Perhaps my HourVarb variable is the wrong format for the numpy code? Alternatively, the 1/1/1900 is causing problems and the format %H: %M: %S needs to change? My end goal is to be able to reference the hour and the date to filter out specific date/hour combinations. Please help.

One note, when I change the HourVarb to '1/1/1900 15:00:00' the code above works as intended, but I'd still like to understand if there is a cleaner way that removes the date. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the problem with the 'object' datatypes of these columns.

I loaded the data you provided this way:

```
df = pd.read_csv('xyz.csv')
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df['Date'] = df['Time'].dt.date
df['Hour'] = df['Time'].dt.time
print(df.dtypes)
```

And I get these data types:

```
Time    datetime64[ns]
Date            object
Hour            object
```

The fact that Date and Hour are object types should not be a problem.  The underlying data is a [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) type:

```
print(type(df.Date.iloc[0]))
print(type(df.Hour.iloc[0]))

<class 'datetime.date'>
<class 'datetime.time'>
```

This means you can use these columns as such.  For example:

```
print(df['Date'] + pd.Timedelta('1D'))
```

What are you trying to do that is requiring the column dtype to be a Pandas dtype?

**UPDATE**

Here is how you achieve the last part of your question:

```
from datetime import datetime, time

hourVarb = datetime.strptime("15:00:00", '%H:%M:%S').time()
# or hourVarb = time(15, 0)
df['Test'] = df['Hour'] == hourVarb
print(df['Test'])

0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: Test, dtype: bool
```

Comment: When I try to apply numpy "np.where" functionality to the Date and Hour objects the functionality doesn't work (or I'm doing something wrong).

Comment: Not sure what you're using `np.where` for. Maybe add that part to the question so we can find a solution. Things like `df.loc[df.Hour >= datetime.time(13, 0)]` work fine so I'm struggling to see the problem of having the Time column as datetime objects.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the 'Hour' column.

Comment: HourVarb = '15:00:00'
df['Test'] = np.where(df['Hour']==HourVarb,1,np.nan)

Comment: See the update to my answer above.